# Проблемы браузера Chrome при создании более одного VPN подключения(pptp)

Tags: windows-10, vpn

При условии созданного хотя бы одного VPN подключения на основе pptp, не включая его. Имею не понятную работу браузера. Во вкладке страницы, кружок загрузки крутится практически вечно. Если подключить VPN соединение, то кружок загрузки практически сразу прекращает работу, т.е. страница полностью загрузилась!

Answer (score 0):

В настройках прокси-сервера в самом браузере ничего лишнего не настроено/добавлено? Какие у вас настройки там? Что уже имеется? Сам пользуюсь на WIN 10, Chrome, VPN - все прекрасно работает. Попробуйте так же отключить антивирус, если имеется, возможно блокирует https соединения.

Comment: Единственное, что VPN-соединение добавляет шлюз. Но я ж так понимаю, что шлюз добавляется когда VPN-соединение активно. Прокси не активно.

Comment: Вообще, после настройки VPN соединения, во вкладке Прокси-сервер, должно появиться это соединение, дабы трафик шел в самом браузере. Попробуйте а) Отключить антивирусные программы ( возможна блокировка HTTPS ( защищенного  ) соединения. 2) Если во вкладке Прокси-Сервер нет ничего, добавить VPN в этой вкладке с использованием протокола pptp.

Comment: Дмитрий, мне частенько надо работать без VPN-соединения. Проблемы возникают с Chrome, когда VPN-соединения не работает.

Comment: @VictorKurenkov У вас основное подключение к интернету происходит через VPN? Или вы поверх своего интернета дополнительно ставите VPN ( Как пример, HideMe ). Попробуйте сменить DNS сервера на google. ( 8.8.4.4)

Comment: Дмитрий, простое подключение к Интернет. Но есть отключенные записи VPN. Помогла вот эта статья https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957539.aspx

Comment: @VictorKurenkov Что знал, то отписал! ;) Хорошо что проблема решилась!